# why javascript is not responsive/firing on ajax callback content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./umeditor/themes/default/_css/umeditor.css">

    <script src="./umeditor/third-party/mathquill/mathquill.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./umeditor/third-party/mathquill/mathquill.css"/>
```

in head of my main page.

When i am calling some content in a modal via ajax .The loaded content doesn't firing these files

Comment: Please, ask something. I don't know what is your problem, neither your question

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and checking if any errors are present? You'll likely want to ensure that all of your files and dependencies are loading properly and in the proper locations as well.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong here? Please use as much details you can. It's quiet unclear what  you are asking here.

Comment: Hey i have edited the question. Hope this will clear.(New Here)